# disable RabbitAutoConfiguration programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a programmatic(properties based) way of disabling RabbitAutoConfiguration  in spring boot (1.2.2).

Looks like spring.rabbitmq.dynamic=false  disables just the AmqpAdmin but not the connection factory etc.

We want a model where app properties might be sourced from spring cloud config (includes control bus) or via -D jvm args. This decision is made at deployment time.
When properties are sourced from -D jvm args, we disable the spring cloud config client but rabbit keeps throwing exceptions such as :

[org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] - [Co
nsumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory suppor
ts it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.ne
t.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to exclude RabbitAutonfiguration from your app

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Then you can import it based on some property like this

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="myproperty",havingValue="valuetocheck",matchIfMissing=false)
@Import(RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
class RabbitOnConditionalConfiguration{

}
```

Comment: It is helpful to the SO community to mark answers as accepted if you feel they answered your question.

Comment: If you use spring cloud stream, don't forget to disable your package containing your channels definitions or any references to Messaging. For instance `@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, pattern = {"yourpackage.web.messaging.*"}))`