# Disable rabbit connection

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a spring cloud config server with `spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit` dependency.

How can I disable the connection to rabbitmq ?

I have tried to exclude in the following ways:

1. https://tech.asimio.net/2017/02/02/Refreshable-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Spring-Cloud-Bus-RabbitMQ-and-Git.html
2. [disable RabbitAutoConfiguration programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845711/disable-rabbitautoconfiguration-programmatically)
3. exclude from the application.yaml:

   > spring: 
   >   autoconfigure:
   >        exclude: the rabbitmq auto configure package + class

, but still get in logs:

> CachingConnectionFactoey: Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
>   and finally throw exception.

Is there any way to disable it and still have `stream-rabbit` dependency?

Comment: Please add, what exactly you have done to disable the connection. Settings? Code?

Comment: Added the links i followed up in the question