# Excluding Only rabbitMqtemplate autoconfiguration in spring boot

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-config

I have configured RabbitMQ in my file SpringCloudConfiguration.

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name={"gssp.amqp.enabled", "rabbitmq.addresses"}, matchIfMissing = false)
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;
}
```

But when I'm trying to run the server, it's showing the following exception:

```
The bean 'rabbitTemplate', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/metlife/gssp/spring/configuration/SpringCloudConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

I have to use the property `"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true"` to for overriding. I don't want to use this property.
Is it possible to exclude this AutoConfiguration `RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class`?

I just want to exclude *RabbitTemplateConfiguration* and not the entire *RabbitAutoConfiguration* as Spring is configuring some other beans as well.

Note:

I tried with this

`spring.autoconfigure.exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration1 in my yml file, but it stops other beans too.

I just want to stop nested class `RabbitAutoConfiguration.RabbitTemplateConfiguration` *autoconfiguration* and simply wants to use my *SpringCloudConfiguration*.

Comment: See this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845711/disable-rabbitautoconfiguration-programmatically

Comment: It excludes entire RabbitAutoConfiguration and not the inner class RabbitTemplateConfiguration

Comment: Can anyone help on this ??