# How to disable RabbitMQ in a SpringBoot Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I have a SpringBootTest

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = {PDFService.class},
        properties = {
                "spring.cloud.config.enabled=false",
                "spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=false",
        })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {RabbitAutoConfiguration.class})
class PDFServiceTest {
```

On start I got this exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
    No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate' available: 
    expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

How can I  disable RabbitMQ in my Tests? Or mock it.

Comment: Is the RabbitAutoConfiguration a class from your project or something you receive trough a dependency? Maybe this Question will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845711/disable-rabbitautoconfiguration-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

It looks like RabbitMQ is disabled and that's actually a reason of the exception you get. Your code contains a bean that gets loaded (and autowired) in the test setup, that looks like this:

```java
@Component
public class MyMessageManager {
   @Autowired
   private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

   public void doSomething() {
      ....
      rabbitTemplate.<...> // use the template 
   }
}
```

When spring test creates the instance of this bean it should be able to inject something that looks like a rabbit template, but since you've disabled it - there is no bean to be injected, hence the error.

How to solve it?
Well, there are many different approaches:

1. Use @MockBean in the test

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = {PDFService.class},
        properties = {
                "spring.cloud.config.enabled=false",
                "spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=false",
        })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {RabbitAutoConfiguration.class})
class PDFServiceTest {
   ...
   @MockBean RabbitTemplate template;
```

Now the mock of rabbit template will be injected into all the beans that need it.

2. Refactor the code in a way that the class that uses RabbitTemplate won't be loaded. Usually it works well if you don't really want to test the functionality of that class.
3. Don't disable Rabbit MQ, instead, try using Test Containers and start rabbit mq before the test, create an infra that will define everything you need to run the code and inject a real rabbit template that works with the test container of rabbit. This is good if you actually want to test the message sending/receiving mechanism